# How can I check if a string in JSON has changed with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to check if a string/date in a JSON file has changed but checking every second. How can I store this value and check the file for change or difference? Any help much appreciated.

```
// json example:
{
  "LastControlUpdateTime": "10:43:06.7147187"
}

var timeStamp;
function CompareTime() {
  $.getJSON(playlistJSONPath, function (data) {
    timeStamp = data.LastControlUpdateTime;

    if (timeStamp === data.LastControlUpdateTime) {
      console.log("same");
    } else {
      console.log("Diff");
    }
  });
}

CompareTime();
setInterval(CompareTime, 1000);
```

Comment: It's part of a bigger file { "name" : "blah", "LastControlUpdateTime": "10:43:06.7147187" }

Comment: You are DDOSing yourself. Use a socket based approach

Comment: Store the date of the last request in as variable and compare it to the one which was last retrieved. ***However*** you should note that AJAX polling is a bad idea, and doing every second is an even worse one as it does not scale. You will DDOS your own server. If you need to keep the UI and server data in close sync use Server Sent Event or Websockets instead.

Comment: I agree to @adiga for "real-time" applications try to implement websocket otherwise increase the time between a poll (rather ~15sec - 60sec), for comparing the dates you could just string-compare the H:i:s part

Comment: How to store? `timeStamp = data.LastControlUpdateTime` ??

Comment: Im still a novice in JS neverheard of websockets befoee but I will look into them now. Thank you.

Comment: @adiga can you please elaborate how are we DDOSing ourself? is it because of the self interval?

Comment: Because that is one call a second to your server with one person. Add in 100s of people that you are constantly just pinging your server over and over again.

Comment: @FarhanQasim if there are 100 clients using this code, that's 100 requests/sec. Also, there is no guarantee they'll complete in the same order. For example, if it's `.net` backend, I'd use `SignalR`. Broadcast to only those clients which need updating only when there's an update.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing the just assigned variable.
this should do it.

```
var old_value;
function CompareTime() {
  $.getJSON(playlistJSONPath, function (data) {
    if (old_value == undefined) {
     old_value = data.LastControlUpdateTime;
    }
    else {
      if (data.LastControlUpdateTime != old_value) {
        console.log("value changed");
        old_value = data.LastControlUpdateTime;
      }
      else {
        console.log("value did not change");
      }
    }
  });
  setTimeout(function() { CompareTime();}, 1000)
}
CompareTime();
```